# weblogic.webservice.core.rpc.StubImpl problems upgrading from Weblogic 10 to Weblogic 12c

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic12c, endpoints

I have been in the process of upgrading from WebLogic 10 to WebLogic 12c.

As I work through many issues, I came across one involving weblogic.webservice.core.rpc.StubImpl.  This version of StubImpl is no longer available in 12c.  My choices are

1) weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.StubImpl
2) weblogic.wsee.tools.clientgen.stubgen.StubImpl

The problem is that I don't know what the original authors were doing with this piece of code, and therefore, I don't know how to keep the original intent.  The method looks like this:

```
public void setEndpoint(Object obj, URL webServiceUrl) throws SystemConfigurationException {

   StubImpl stub = null;
   if ( obj instanceof StubImpl ) 
   {
      stub = (StubImpl)obj;
      stub._setTargetEndPoint(webServiceUrl);
   } else
   {
      ... message ...
      throw SystemConfigurationException(message);
   }
}
```

My questions are:

1) Does anybody know what this method is doing?
2) What is StubImpl?  What is it intended to do? 
3) _setTargetEndPoint is not available in either of the Weblogic 12c versions of StubImpl.  Is there an equivalent call or set of calls?
4) Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks for any advice, tips, etc.